# Error: invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal hex string without 0x prefix into Go struct field TransactionArgs.data of type hexutil.Bytes

Tags: ethereum, solidity, geth

Make solidity file and compile with this
`solcjs --bin --abi -o bin HelloWorld.sol`

`HelloWorld.sol`

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

contract HelloWorld{
    address owner;
    string greeting = "Hello World";
    function HelloWorld() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    function greet () constant public returns (string){
        return greeting;

    }
    function kill () public {
        require(owner == msg.sender);
        selfdestruct(owner);
    }
}
```

`HelloWorld_sol_HelloWorld.bin` file is made.

then start `geth console --rinkeby`

set bytecode in console like this

```
>bytecode =
"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"
```

Now try to send this

`>tx = eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0],data:bytecode,gas:500e3})`

comes the error below.

`Error: invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal hex string without 0x prefix into Go struct field TransactionArgs.data of type hexutil.Bytes`

Why it happens??

Comment: Add 0x prefix in bytecode - ```bytecode ="0x606060405260408...```

Comment: Thank you , however `Error: transaction type not supported` happens.